# c++ unordered map using templates

Tags: templates

I am trying to declare an unordered map using templates in c++. However, as I expect the object to be one of the primitive datatypes I don't want to declare a custom class for only one object.

I've tried using :

```
template <class T> std::unordered_map<int, T> storedObj;
```

but I keep getting the error: **‘storedObj’ was not declared in this scope**

a code snippet is below

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<deque>



        std::deque<int> freeIds;
        template <class T> std::unordered_map<int, T> storedObj;
            unsigned static int objIdCount=0;
        const unsigned long int MAXID = 1000000000;
```

Can you please tell me what's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `partial template specialisation` here (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization). Probably what you had in mind is a `typedef`-like construction but that doesn't work with templates.

With partial template specialisation you can (partially) re-implement or re-define a templated type.

One way to achieve your goal could be:

```
template <class T>
class my_unordered_map :
    public std::unordered_map<int, T>
{
};

int main( void ) {
    my_unordered_map<float>  mf;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Templates are used for compile-time polymorphism. You cannot instantiate a template-based class without specifying an actual datatype for that template.

A basic way to use templates would be:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class MyClass {
    T foo;
public:
    MyClass(T bar) {
        foo = bar;
    }
    void print() {
        cout << foo;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass<int> c(5);
    c.print(); // prints 5
    return 0;
}
```

You can achieve what you're trying to do by extending (deriving) the unordered_map class, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class MyClass: public unordered_map<int, T> {
    // optional extra code here
};

int main() {
    MyClass<string> cstring;
    cstring[0] = "foo";
    cout << cstring[0] << "\n"; // prints "foo"

    MyClass<double> cdouble;
    cdouble[0] = 3.14; // prints 3.14
    cout << cdouble[0];

    return 0;
}
```